# How to set format of JSpinner DateEditor?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

How to set the format for date Editor of `JSpinner`? I don't want to set the format in the constructor, I want to set the format later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to set the format later.

Then create a new editor with the format and add the editor to the spinner when you know what format you want to use.